# Cannot switch to other window handle with WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver

So I have this code for an IE driver (The website only works with IE...):

```
PrintStream out;
try {
    out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
    System.setOut(out);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Main Handle: " + driver.getWindowHandle());

element = driver.findElement(By.id("lnk"));
element.click();

//try {
//  Thread.sleep(1000);
//} catch (InterruptedException e) {
//  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//  e.printStackTrace();
//}

try{
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        System.out.println(winHandle);
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("na bro, unlucky");
}

System.out.println("end");

System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

there should be two window handles, which there appears to be from the println.  But it can only switch to the main one, the window that pops up cannot be switched to.  There are two possible outputs, even though I run the program the same time.  It's just chance which I will get.  The first output is:

Main Handle: cd484ff9-3dbd-487d-bfa3-805f19b1ff9d

cd484ff9-3dbd-487d-bfa3-805f19b1ff9d

005d28b9-1c4d-40cf-95ab-1782f2dc53fd

end

which results in an error of:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Which means it was able to switch but then it didn't exist???? That's really weird.  The second output possible is:

Main Handle: cd9fe661-7257-48ff-93c1-17c89b1f9443

cd9fe661-7257-48ff-93c1-17c89b1f9443

2d96e296-47a2-4cd1-b994-89a2cbe4f045

na bro, unlucky

end

and then it proceeds to print out the page source of the main handle.  I don't understand why it can't grab that second handle?  What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a thread.sleep(10000) before and after the code for switching windows

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        System.out.println(winHandle);
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }

    Thread.sleep(10000);
}catch(InterruptedException e) {
    e.printstacktrace();
}catch(Exception ee){
    System.out.println("na bro, unlucky");
}

System.out.println("end");
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Also try to get the title of the currentwindow using driver.getTitle() to see if the switch is successful.

Comment: Sleeping before and after, no matter how long of a delay I put, results in only one handle in the `getWindowHandles`.  For some reason the second handle for the popped up window disappears right away.